# Pushing data from a sensor to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arduino, sensors

I would like to push my data from sensor to a non-sql database.

Let me give a overview of my project outline.

```
Sensor-->Databse-->Webserver(node.js+express)-->IOS device(RestKit)
```

As it can be seen, I have a web server developed using node and express. The web server as of now, reads a value from MongoDB database and the value is displayed onto an IOS device.

I would now like to store the values from a sensor to a non-SQL database(Preferably MongoDB).

To test the whole setup i would use Arduino as sensor to measure temperature.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use one of the available MongoDB REST interfaces (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) or write a very basic one of your own.

Very rough sketch:

```
// assuming express app and mongodb native module with open collection
app.post('/datapoint', function(req, res) {
    collection.insert(req.body, function(err, record) {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.send('Datapoint stored as ' + record.id);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for replying. But isn't the above example, is to store data into mongoDB, what if I want to store data from a sensor such as Arduino?

Comment: I have little knowledge of Arduino's, but my assumption was that it would be fairly easy to do a HTTP POST with some data in the body. The protocol isn't very difficult. If not, it really depends on how the Arduino can interface over a network connection.

Comment: First useful search result I got: https://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/arduino-http-client-library/

Answer (score 2):

How is the Arduino hardware connected to the system?

If it is connected directly over the serial port, you can just reuse parts of my code at:
[Arduino sensor logging with collectd & RRDtool](https://github.com/jeroendoggen/Arduino-serial-messaging/tree/master/Clients/Collectd)

In this example, I write Arduino measurements to a RRDtool database.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. My Arduino is connected via USB and this seems a really good example to get my hands dirty. I will definitely give it a serious look.